# Static member variable and thread safety

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application.

I have a ViewModel class for which I am trying to maintain a count in order to generate div ids which are used in a view:

```
public class ViewModel {

    private static uint instanceCount;
    private readonly uint id;

    public ViewModel(){
        id = instanceCount++;
    }

    public uint DivId
    {
        get { return id; }
    }
}
```

Am I correct in thinking incrementing and assigning the static member is not threadsafe and thus not safe in a web application?

What is the best way to make this safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking incrementing and assigning the static member is not threadsafe and thus not safe in a web application?

Yes, you are correct into thinking this.

> What is the best way to make this safe?

By synchronizing the access:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private static uint instanceCount;
    private readonly uint id;
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        lock(_syncRoot)
        {
            id = instanceCount++;
        }
    }

    public uint DivId
    {
        get { return id; }
    }
}
```

or simply use a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel
    {
        DivId = string.Format("id_{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    public string DivId { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I initially condsidered a Guid but didn't like the length of the resulting ids. I've now decided to keep things simple and use a Guid. I have gained a bit of knowledge on statics and threading as a result - Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have to ask, why you can't just handle this within your view:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var models = SomeService.GetModels(); // returns IEnumerable<YourViewModel>
    return View(models);
}

// in your view

@for (int i = 1; i == Model.Count(); i++) {
    <div id="div-@i">
        <!-- your content here -->
    </div>
}
```

Comment: The view allows editing of a nested collection which can be added to dynamically - I don't know how many Models there will be.

Comment: You don't need to know in advance. That's what the Model.Count() is for (assuming your Model is a collection)

Comment: But if items are added to the list dynamically using ajax/javascript? I guess another option would be to use javascript to count the number of existing rows when adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) instead. However, this works only with an signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment()` method. That's will be right choice in your case. See [Interlocked class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) for more info.