# passing a view-model with a controller around multiple Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have 3 views, a controller and one model. (just an example) The first view sets the user first name and last name. Which gets posted back to the controller, and I can see the data in the view-model. The controller then calls the second view sets the email (I can call the data from view 1).  The third view shows all of the data (the original stuff from view 1 is no longer there)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Email)
```

Do you think creating a static singleton model would work in the controller? or should I be using TempData

EDIT: sorry I forgot about my controller

Would my GET methods in my controller need a parameter?

```
   [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult SignUp1(model m)
    {
        return View(m)
    }
```

Comment: Why are your views passing a model to each other?  You should be hitting the controller between page loads...

Comment: @Bobson completely left out my controller in the question. Its there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static is a bad idea for web pages, because it is not inherently thread-safe ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6505715/298754)).  That means that you'll get really bizarre behavior if you have two or more people using it at once.

I'm not sure why you're even considering doing it this way - is there some specific reason you're thinking about it?  The proper way to do it would be to post the model back to each controller action from each view, populating more data each time.  Alternatively, you could post back to the same action, and then return the appropriate view based on which fields are missing from the model (and the display if none are).

Comment: yes to the middle part! I want to be building the model as I go through the views, I can't get this happen though, unless I should have hidden fields to repopulate what I already populated in the view before it

Comment: @FreshJays - Yep, that would be the best way to do it.  Alternatives include storing it in a database or in `Session`.  You don't want to use `ViewData` or `TempData` because they won't persist past the post, IIRC.

Comment: thank you so much so far! Here is the problem when I try implementing that way:
View1 I set the Firstname -> View2 I can retrieve and read the Firstname -> when I post the form from View2 to my Post method, in model the firstname is blank. It was cleared

Comment: :) I think it will, let me try it out, hopefully the data remains

Comment: the data did not remain, first name and last name are still blank... I think hidden fields are my only option?

Comment: Have you tried outputting first name and last name to make sure they're being passed to the view in the first place?  If not, hidden fields won't work either.

Comment: Yes they are being displayed in view2. So I can write @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName) and it works, but I can't seem to pass that value again, without resetting it

Comment: Without more of your view and controller code, I can't think of anything else to try.  Sorry.

Comment: I think I will just save to database until I find something that works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can call into another view using @`Html.Partial("view name", object)` if you want to preform logic you can call another controller action with `@Html.Action("action", "controller", object)`. then it's just like any other controller action. typically calling actions from a view are decorated with `[ChildActionOnly]`